# Display recipients email in To instead of BCC while sending in BCC

Tags: c#, email

I would like to send bulk mails in BCC but the recipients should see the email in TO field instead of BCC, is any way to do it ?

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Comment: could you please post the snippet that add BCC

Comment: Send one e-mail per person (TO) rather than one e-mail to many (BCC). Consider that the sending server might be blacklisted if you do so in way that your mail is classified to be spam.